IDLE Python Shell restarts when importing Ultralytics
Im working with Python 3.9 on a Raspberry Pi 4. Whenever I try to import Ultralytics or any of its functions for my code, the shell just restarts without showing any error codes. I tested it on simple codes that dont use ultralytics and just importing the dependency and the result is the described, so it has to be ultralytics thats causing the issue.
I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling ultralytics multiple times, but it changed nothing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
